# Uniswap 'interface' cannot resolve 'fs' polyfill

Tags: uniswap, nodejs, typescript

I've just installed the uniswap interface project i've run the following:

```
yarn
yarn postinstall
yarn graphql
yarn contracts
yarn ajv
yarn i18n
```

When I got to yarn start, I'm receiving the following errors:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@lingui/message-utils/dist/generateMessageId.mjs 1:0-28
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\uniswap\interface\node_modules@lingui\message-utils\dist'

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\uniswap\interface\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist'

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\uniswap\interface\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist'

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in 'C:\uniswap\interface\node_modules\import-fresh\node_modules\resolve-from'

Note no modifications have been made to the projects.
I'm running Node: v18.17.1 on windows.

I would assume the project should just work out of the box no? Any insight on how to fix this?

Comment: I don't use windows, yarn or npm, but just guessing you don't have those modules installed, have you tried something like `npm install package-name` or `yarn add package-name`?

Comment: Those are polyfills, that are missing.  I can try to add them but this is a project used by thousands of people shouldn't it work out of the box?

Comment: Could expect to install some core system or dev tools, but os looks like it comes with npm so maybe it is package lock or version issue. Someone with experience can better help.